# Alignment issues with Badges in List Group Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `badges` in a `list-group` and have problem aligning the badge vertically. If the text length is such that it almost fills the list-group width, then the badges gets pushed down.

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdrfuu43/ Please move the result panel to find cases when the text width is same as list-group width.

[image]

Comment: you can use overflow:auto;

Comment: actually overflow:auto works, but it would be great if I can wrap the text near the badge instead of pushing the badge below.

Comment: try this style.     overflow: auto; display: inline-flex;

Comment: this works in principle but messes up in real. The text is wrapped nicely but the badges background expands the whole height

Comment: can you fix for height?

Comment: that works. thanks vel. can you please post this as answer ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mdrfuu43/7/

Comment: I post my answer @TheWanderer

Comment: Accept my answer if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted here. Try this

```
.badge{
     overflow: auto; 
     display: inline-flex;
     height: 20px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my fiddle, I have wrapped the text and badges in separate wrappers.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/mdrfuu43/4/

If you want your badges stay the right side without going down, then check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/mdrfuu43/8/